# Проблема с сессией: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php, сессия

Изначально когда проектировал сайт, работал с сессиями только на одной странице, где объявлял `session_start();` Потом понадобилось распространить эту функцию на весь сайт. Для этого я разместил `session_start()` в файл `config.php`, который в свою очередь подключается к каждому файлу php сайта. Вот тут-то и возникли проблемы...

Структура сайта такова (заголовочные файлы):

- config.php
- header.php
- left.php
- footer.php

Эти файлы подключаются к каждой странице сайта.
А страницы разбиты по категориям в которых нет ошибки сессии:

- index.php
- shopingcart.php
- contact.php

И файлы в которых ошибка возникает:

- faqs.php
- productdetail.php
- checkout.php

Как можно побороть ошибку данную?

> **Warning:** *session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\faqs.php:1) in
>   S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\config.php on line 2*

Comment: Файлы которые как вы указали содержат ошибку - уберите из них session_start() т.к. он уже был вызван в конфиге

Comment: дело в том, что в них нету session_start(). Есть только один session_start() в конфиге, и каждый ошибочный файл ругается на него, так все подключают конфиг на первой строчке кода.

Comment: я и так подключаю конфиг самой первой строкой в файлах, только в одних нет ошибки, а в других она возникает. Меня смущает избирательность ошибки, с чем она связанна?

Comment: Файлы в которых возникает ошибка сохраните в кодировке UTF8 без BOM, если конечно используете UTF

Comment: Ответом ниже верный ответ...

Comment: у меня и так стоит utf без BOM. Ошибка не в этом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Благодаря помощи, товарища [ToRcH565](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10415/torch565) удалось исправить эту ошибку. Дело было в том, что я писал `<?php` не с нулевой позиции.

Comment: мой ответ неверен был) я лиш указал в каком символе ошибка в BOM, так что принимайте тот что есть он верен))

Comment: да ладно, не скромничайте))

Answer (score 9):

Ошибка говорит о том, что функция не может установить заголовки ответа HTTP, так как уже был вывод данных в тело ответа.
Функция header (которую в свою очередь вызывает session_start) может использоваться только до вывода тела ответа.
Чтобы исправить ошибку разместите подключение config.php в самом начале текста файла.
Если это не помогло или так и есть уже, то пересохраните файл без BOM.

Comment: Согласен, неверно прочел ошибку.. про бом поясните человеку, я с трудом понял о чем вы(символы до <?..) если я верно понял...

Comment: Да, верно. Если кодировка с BOM, то в файле:  

    <?
    include("config.php");
    ?>
Перед **<?** находятся два символа которые PHP определяет как тело ответа и не может более устанавливать заголовки.

Comment: Конфиг у меня подключается первым к файлу header.php, а тот в свою очередь стоит на первой строке всех файлов. И все файлы у меня и так без BOM. Причем тут BOM не пойму?

Comment: Скиньте файлы в архиве(в конфиге пароли затрите). именно те которые дают ошибку, посмотрю что там не так..

Comment: вот ссылка на мой архив-сайта http://my-files.ru/kbsj.web_shop.rar

Comment: как я и думал.. все верно вам сказали, скрин http://88.198.134.41/faqs.jpg

Ошибку красным обвел, исправляйте, точнее удаляйте лишний символ и радуйтесь рабочим скриптам

Comment: productdetail.php - первые подключения явно не конфиг.

checkout.php - тот же символ.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь! Напиши свой ответ не комментарием, а ответом, я тебе отмечу как правильный ответ.)

Answer (score 2):

Может кому то и поможет!
Открыл файл в Notepad++ и сохранил его с кодировкой UTF-8 без BOM. 
И перезалил файл на хостинг. 
После обновление страницы, предупреждение исчезла!

Спасибо всем за наводку :)