# Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent WARNING

Tags: warning

Выдает ошибку:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at D:\OSPanel\domains\tAKNYT\index.php:4)
>   in D:\OSPanel\domains\tAKNYT\blocks\header.php on line 3

Вот код header:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            "use strict";
            //================ Проверка email ==================

            //регулярное выражение для проверки email
            var pattern = /^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\._-]*[a-z0-9]*@([a-z0-9]+([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]+/i;
            var mail = $('input[name=email]');

            mail.blur(function(){
                if(mail.val() != ''){

                    // Проверяем, если введенный email соответствует регулярному выражению
                    if(mail.val().search(pattern) == 0){
                        // Убираем сообщение об ошибке
                        $('#valid_email_message').text('');

                        //Активируем кнопку отправки
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                    }else{
                        //Выводим сообщение об ошибке
                        $('#valid_email_message').text('Не правильный Email');

                        // Дезактивируем кнопку отправки
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#valid_email_message').text('Введите Ваш email');
                }
            });

            //================ Проверка длины пароля ==================
            var password = $('input[name=password]');

            password.blur(function(){
                if(password.val() != ''){

                    //Если длина введенного пароля меньше шести символов, то выводим сообщение об ошибке
                    if(password.val().length < 6){
                        //Выводим сообщение об ошибке
                        $('#valid_password_message').text('Минимальная длина пароля 6 символов');

                        // Дезактивируем кнопку отправки
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);

                    }else{
                        // Убираем сообщение об ошибке
                        $('#valid_password_message').text('');

                        //Активируем кнопку отправки
                        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#valid_password_message').text('Введите пароль');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="/" title="Перейти на главную">
            <span>Н</span>овости
        </a>
    </div>
<div id="auth_block">   
<?php 
        //Проверяем авторизован ли пользователь
        if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) && !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
        // если нет, то выводим блок с ссылками на страницу регистрации и авторизации
?>
        <div id="regAuth">
        <a href="/signup.php">Регистрация</a> | <a href="login.php">Авторизация</a>     
        </div>
<?php
        }else{
?>          
        <div id="link_logout">
            <a href="/logout.php">Выход</a>
        </div>  
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</header>
</html>
```

А вот код index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
    $title = "tAKNYT";
    require_once "blocks/head.php";
?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php require_once "blocks/header.php" ?>   
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="bigArticle">
                <img src="/img/articles/1.jpg" alt="Статья 1" title="Статья 1">
                <h2>Статья 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
                <a href="/article.php">
                    <div class="more">Далее</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"><br></div>
            <div class="article">
                <img src="/img/articles/2.jpg" alt="Статья 1" title="Статья 1">
                <h2>Статья 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
                <a href="/article.php">
                    <div class="more">Далее</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="article">
                <img src="/img/articles/3.jpg" alt="Статья 1" title="Статья 1">
                <h2>Статья 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
                <a href="/article.php">
                    <div class="more">Далее</div>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>

    <?php require_once "blocks/footer.php" ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с сессией: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/247691/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-headers-already-sent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_start(); перенесите из header.php в index.php

Из мануала :

> Замечание: Для использования сессий на основе cookie, функция
>   session_start() должна быть вызвана перед выводом чего бы то ни было в
>   браузер.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php

Comment: Огромное спасибо, проблема решена.